# Frequency Transmitter

Tags: frequency, generator

I was wondering if anyone had any site or diagram for a cheap (and preferably small) for a circuit for a 60 to 80khz frequency generator.

Comment: do you mean a tone generator? or a function generation? do you need a square wave, sine wave or saw tooth?

Comment: They are usually called [oscillator circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator), so try searching for that term.

Comment: Im trying to build an ultrasonic pest repeller.Im assuming that it will generate a tone at 80 KHz constantly. Im not sure if the shape of the wave matters.

Comment: What are you using to emit sound?  Piezo or regular speaker?

Answer (score 4):

This relaxation oscillator must be the most simple you can find:

[image]

Comment: Should be mentioned that the symbol in the inverter means it has a Schmitt trigger input.  It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

[My version of Jesper's MiniDDS](http://webspace.webring.com/people/jl/leon_heller/minidds.html) will give you a variety of waveforms at 60 kHz to 80 kHz. It can be built for about £10.

Comment: Im trying to build an ultrasonic pest repeller. Would this circuit work for an applicaion like that? I don't know why my science professor wants me to make it up to 80 KHz though...

Comment: Leon's solution is overkill for what you need, but I presume he posted it before he knew exactly what your application was.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a [Hartley oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_oscillator) or a [Colpitts oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator).  If you know some basic electronics, you could easily design your own [RLC circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit).

Comment: Im trying to build an ultrasonic pest repeller. Would this circuit work for that? This is for a science project at school. Thanks for your help!